# Get few words from string on the left and on the right of keyword

Tags: c#, regex, string, search, text

Let's assume I have some text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

1. If I query for "sed do" I want to get "sed to" + additional 2 words on the left and on the right. In this case I want to get:

> adipiscing elit, **sed do** eiusmod tempor

2. If I query for "aliqua" I want to get:

> dolore magna **aliqua**

etc

I believe the best way is to do it with Regex (it's not must-have), but I don't know how to construct such a query.

Comment: you can use `if-else` condition and two regexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by surrounding the target word with `\s?\S*\s?\S*`, like this:

```
\S*\s?\S*\s?consectetur\s?\S*\s?\S*
```

[demo 1.](https://regex101.com/r/fR9rD5/1)

Since space `\s` is optional and `\S*` can match zero characters, this works on both ends of the text as well ([demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/cT0sG2/1), [demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/cR9fU5/2)).

**Note:** This approach does not work too well when words are separated by multiple spaces, because it relies on counting whitespace.

Comment: Regarding multiple spaces why we can adjust it with asterisk? So finally it can looks like: \S*\s*\S*\s*\S*\bSOMETEXT\b\S*\s*\S*\s*\S*